# как создать объектную модель данных для Dictionary в Swift?

Tags: swift4, модель-данных

я новичок, изучаю Swift самостоятельно. Подскажите как создать объектную модель данных?  Контент такой - есть список студентов по классам, и есть несколько таких классов. Эти данные надо вывести в двух таблицах - в одной список классов, в другой - пользователь выбирает класс и ему показывается список студентов.

Сделал такую модель:

```
struct Student {
    var name: String
}

struct CollegeClass {
    var title: String
    var students: [Student]
}

var collegeClass = CollegeClass(title: "9A", students: ["Ivanov", "Petrov", "Sidorov"])
```

Но выдает ошибку - Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected element type 'Student'
Что здесь неправильно? Как создать словарь, чтобы потом передать из него данные в таблицу?

Update: add secondClass

```
arrayCollegeClass.append(CollegeClass(title: "9B", students: [Student(name: "Orlov"), Student(name: "Pavlov"), Student(name: "Semenov")]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `students` класса `CollegeClass` является массивом `Student`, а не массивом `String`. Даже несмотря на то, что `Student` пока что обладает лишь одним свойством, `collegeClass` надо инициализировать именно так:

```
var collegeClass = CollegeClass(title: "9A", students: [Student(name: "Ivanov"), Student(name: "Petrov"), Student(name: "Sido")])
```

Если хотите, чтобы `students` был больше похож на массив строк, добавьте такое расширение:

```
extension String {
    var asStudentName: Student {
        return Student(name: self)
    }
}
```

И тогда `collegeClass` будет инициализироваться вот так:

```
var collegeClass = CollegeClass(title: "9A", students: ["Ivanov".asStudentName, "Petrov".asStudentName, "Sido".asStudentName])
```

Предположим, что информация обо всех классах у Вас хранится в подобном массиве:

```
let arrayCollegeClass = [
    CollegeClass(title: "9A", students: [Student(name: "Ivanov"), Student(name: "Petrov"), Student(name: "Sido")]),
    CollegeClass(title: "9B", students: [Student(name: "Orlov"), Student(name: "Pavlov"), Student(name: "Semenov")])
]
```

Тогда Вы сможете получить список учеников для класса с определённым названием с помощью следующей функции:

```
func students(of classTitle: String,
              arrayCollegeClass: [CollegeClass]) -> [Student]? {
    return arrayCollegeClass.first { $0.title == classTitle }?.students
}
```

Вызывайте её вот так:

```
students(of: "9A", arrayCollegeClass: arrayCollegeClass)
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как достать значения по ключу? Например, нужно получить фамилии студентов "9А" класса.

Comment: @maxMas Так у Вас же 1 класс только. Добавьте в вопрос хотя бы ещё один класс с учениками.

Comment: добавил еще один класс

Comment: @maxMas Я обновил свой ответ.